# Speakers quiet while headpones are loud

Tags: windows-8.1, audio

I think that after the recent windows 8.1 update volume of the speakers droped drastically. While if I plug in the headphones the volume is normal.

This is what "playback window" looks like. In both cases the same youtube video is playing. In left case youtube volume and computer volume are both set to maximum. While in the right case the computer volume is set to only 45.
[image: volume]

Comment: Tried updating the drivers ?

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like I did. Nothing changed